# liferay find util NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: liferay, velocity

I can not load this liferay utils:

`#set($formUtil= $utilLocator.findUtil("com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.TextFormatter"))`

I receive this error:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.TextFormatter' is defined`

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way is to use default Liferay velocity variables. See the full description here: http://www.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+Objects+from+Velocity

I can think you need something like `dateFormats` or `stringUtil`.

Answer (score 1):

Class com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.TextFormatter is not a bean defined in spring context in liferay (this is what the exception says). It is a class that privides static methods. You would use your solution to access e.g. UserLocalServiceUtil.

I have never tried this solution but it should work:

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#supportforstaticclasses